# Find all condition matching fields in Firebase Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a scoring system for referees. The referees working on a specific station and can select their current team in the scoring system. They insert their score and upload it to the database.

The database is structured in the following way:
[image]

The group stands for the teams district and the subgroup for their age group. Both together forms the unique team. The referees can select the district, the age group and the score. The score object is stored in the collection **Points** like this:

[image]

The referees should get the option to see all their scoring inserts. I could now go through the whole database and check everywhere, if the stations is equal to the referees station. And now the final question: **Is this kind of solution really fitting for my problem or are there better and easier way e.g. store there inserts in another collection as well.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firestore, there are collection group queries, which allow you to query across different collections with the same id (e.g. over all points collections), see the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

You could also store the inserts in a separate collection under the referee for example, which may be handy when defining security rules etc. depending on your architecture.